# Bijection between $\operatorname{Hom}_{Grps}(G, U(R))$ and $\operatorname{Hom}_{Rings}(\Bbb{Z}G, R)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I would like to find a bijection between $\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathbf{Grps}}(G, U(R))$ and $\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathbf{Rings}}(\Bbb{Z}G, R)$, where $U(R)$ is the group of units and $\Bbb{Z}G$ is the free abelian group on $G$ with a ring structure defined in the obvious manner on the basis elements. Let the basis elements be $g_1, \dots g_n$

The maps $\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathbf{Rings}} \to \operatorname{Hom}_{\mathbf{Grps}}$, $f \mapsto f^*$ where $f^*(g_i) = f(g_i)$ and $\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathbf{Grps}} \to \operatorname{Hom}_{\mathbf{Rings}}$, $f^* \mapsto f$, where $f(g_i) = f^*(g_i)$ ($f$ is determined by its value at the basis elements) are clearly inverse to each other.  Does this establish the bijection?

Comment: You say that the two maps «clearly are inverse to each other» yet you immediately ask if this establishes a bijection?

Answer (score 1):

You know in general that a ring map $R\to S$ restricts to a group map $H\to S^\times$ for any $H\leqslant R^\times$. Since $\mathbb{Z}[G]^\times\supseteq G$ this implies that a ring map $\mathbb{Z}[G]\to R$ gives rise a group map $G\to U(R)$. Let us denote this map $\text{Hom}_\mathbf{Ring}(\mathbb{Z}[G],R)\to\text{Hom}_\mathbf{Grp}(G,R^\times)$ by $F$. Now, if we have a a group map $G\to U(R)$ we get a ring map $\mathbb{Z}[G]\to R$ defined by extending the action $\mathbb{Z}$-linearly. Let us denote this association $\text{Hom}_\mathbf{Grp}(G,R^\times)\to\text{Hom}_\mathbf{Ring}(\mathbb{Z}[G],R)$ by $G$. We claim that $F$ and $G$ are inverses. Indeed, if we start with $f:G\to R^\times$, then $G(f)$ is a ring map $\mathbb{Z}[G]\to R$ and thus the restriction map $F:g\mapsto g\mid_G$ sends $G(f)$ back to $f$. Conversely, if $\phi:\mathbb{Z}[G]\to R$ then $F(\phi):G\to R^\times$ is just restriction, and we get the ring map $G(F(\phi)):\mathbb{Z}[G]\to R$. Since $(G\circ F)(\phi)$ and $\phi$ agree (by construction) on the $\mathbb{Z}$-algebra basis $G$ of $\mathbb{Z}[G]$ they must be equal. Thus, $F=G^{-1}$ as desired.

The important thing about this construction is that one can easily show that we actually have an adjunction between the group ring functor and units functor (the group ring functor being the left adjoint of course). This is easy to diagram chase and I leave it to you.

Comment: It s not quite true that $\mathbb Z[G]^\times=G$. What the left hand side is, exactly, is in fact an open problem in many cases!

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez I put = instead of contains. My mistake.

Answer (score 1):

For $f\colon \mathbb{Z}G\to R$ we note (viewing $G$ as a subset of $\mathbb{Z}G$) that $f(g)\in R^\times$ because $f(g)f(g^{-1})=f(gg^{-1})=f(e)=1$, hence $f\mapsto f|_G$ is a map $\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathbf {Ring}}(\mathbb{Z}G,R)\to \operatorname{Hom}_{\mathbf {Grp}}(\mathbb G,R^\times)$.
Conversely, given a group homomorphism $g\colon G\to R^\times\subseteq R$, this extends uniquely to a ring homomorphism $\mathbb{Z}G\to R$ by definition.
As you note yourself, these two maps are clearly inverse of each other, hence establish a natural(!) bijection.